# ruby bundle install prefix

Tags: ruby, installation, rvm, bundle

I am trying to install a bundle and specifying the path to my rvm:

`bundle install --path /home/abc/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@mygemset/`

However the package when installing always add a prefix to it, so my installed file is ended up in:

`/home/abc/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@mygemset/ruby/1.9.1/*`

I can't find where did this `ruby/1.9.1` come from... Please give me a hint.

```
$rvm --version
rvm 1.19.1 (stable)

$ ruby --version
ruby 1.9.3p392 (2013-02-22 revision 39386) [x86_64-linux]

$ bundle --version
Bundler version 1.3.5

$ which ruby
/home/abc/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin/ruby

which bundle
/home/danghvu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@mygemset/bin/bundle

$ rvm gemset list

gemsets for ruby-1.9.3-p392 (found in /home/abc/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392)
   (default)
=> mygemset
```

Comment: why is this prefix a problem for you? what kind of rvm version do you have?

Comment: I added the version. It breaks most of the thing, for example there are some executable files in `[rvmdir]/ruby/1.9.1/bin/*` that is not in my path, only `[rvmdir]/bin` is.

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question, but I had the same setup without any problems. What happens, if you add [rvmdir]/ruby/1.9.1/bin/ to your path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem, since the bundle install to the folder without the knowledge of the current ruby, it assumes ones based on requirement of the gem inside the bundle.

Solution: can't be solved using bundle install --path, use `gem build` then `gem install`